# JAVA for creating all possible combination of words

Tags: java, string, combinations

I am trying to get all the possible combinations of words input by user. Such as words input like `aa, bb, cc` should give

```
aa
bb
cc
aabb
aacc
bbaa
bbcc
ccaa
ccbb
aabbcc
aaccbb
bbaacc
bbccaa
ccbbaa
ccaabb
```

They can in any order but preferably in sorted order.

I have been trying to accomplish this for past hour and I think I am confused about something that I can't figure out and keep going in circles. Can someone please point me in the right direction.

The code so far is

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WordCombination {
private static String[] wordlist;
private static String[] wordcomb;

public static void main(String[] argv){
    Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter Words:");
    setWords(a.nextLine());

    creatCombinations();

}

private static void setWords(String words){
    System.out.println("Entered words: " + words);
    wordlist = words.split("\\s+");
    Arrays.sort(wordlist);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(wordlist));
}

private static void creatCombinations(){
    int size = wordlist.length;
    int perm = (int) Math.pow(size, size);
    int c = 1;

    wordcomb = new String[perm];

    String word = "";
    /*
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        word = wordlist[i];         
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            word += wordlist[j];            
            System.out.println(c + ": " + word + ".com");
            c++;
        }
        word = "";
    }*/
    int l = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        int permj = (i+1) * size;
        System.out.println("------------------> " + permj + " permutations for " + (i + 1) + " words combination");
        int iterations = permj * (i+1);
        System.out.println(" Iterations: " + iterations);
        word = wordlist[i];
        for(int j = 0; j < permj; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < i+1; k++){
                int permi = i * size;
                int index = permi + (k%permj);
                wordcomb[c-1] += "" + wordlist[l%size];
                out(l%size + "");
                l++;
            }
            System.out.println(c + ": " + wordcomb[c-1]);
            c++;
        }
        word = "";
    }

}

private static void out(String s){
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

}

**Edit: The output I am getting is **

```
    Enter Words:1 2 3
Entered words: 1 2 3
[1, 2, 3]
------------------> 3 permutations for 1 words combination
 Iterations: 3
0
1: 1
1
2: 2
2
3: 3
------------------> 6 permutations for 2 words combination
 Iterations: 12

Enter Words:aa bb cc
Entered words: aa bb cc
[aa, bb, cc]
------------------> 3 permutations for 1 words combination
 Iterations: 3
0
1: aa
1
2: bb
2
3: cc
------------------> 6 permutations for 2 words combination
 Iterations: 12
0
1
4: aabb
2
0
5: ccaa
1
2
6: bbcc
0
1
7: aabb
2
0
8: ccaa
1
2
9: bbcc
------------------> 9 permutations for 3 words combination
 Iterations: 27
0
1
2
10: aabbcc
0
1
2
11: aabbcc
0
1
2
12: aabbcc
0
1
2
13: aabbcc
0
1
2
14: aabbcc
0
1
2
15: aabbcc
0
1
2
16: aabbcc
0
1
2
17: aabbcc
0
1
2
18: aabbcc
```

Comment: Why have you created a String array of size = `size ^ size`. The total number of such combination possible would be `2 ^ size`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/127704/1679863)

Comment: Can you give a high-level explanation of your code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approach is fundamentally flawed. In your output, the first character of a permutation = the last character of the previous one + 1, and each character of a permutation = the previous character + 1, which is not how permutation work. So I don't think it can easily be fixed.

Below is a working way to do it, using recursion. It simply tries every character in a position, then recurses to the next position.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NewMain
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      c = Arrays.asList("aa","bb","cc").toArray(new String[0]);
      permutation(0);
      System.out.println("Number of permutations = " + count);
   }

   static String[] c;
   static int count = 0;

   static void swap(int pos1, int pos2)
   {
      String temp = c[pos1];
      c[pos1] = c[pos2];
      c[pos2] = temp;
   }

   public static void permutation(int start)
   {
      if (start != 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < start; i++)
            System.out.print(c[i]);
         System.out.println();
         count++;
      }

      for (int i = start; i < c.length; i++)
      {
         swap(start, i);
         permutation(start + 1);
         swap(start, i);
      }
   }
}
```

Prints:

```
aa
aabb
aabbcc
aacc
aaccbb
bb
bbaa
bbaacc
bbcc
bbccaa
cc
ccbb
ccbbaa
ccaa
ccaabb
Number of permutations = 15
```

Answer (score 5):

One problem is that `wordcomb[c-1]` starts off as `null`, not an empty string. When you add to it, `null` gets converted to `"null"` and the rest gets added to it.

So you need to initialize `wordcomb[c-1]` to an empty string:

```
for(int j = 0; j < permj; j++){
    wordcomb[c-1] = ""; // <--------------------------
    for(int k = 0; k < i+1; k++){
        int permi = i * size;
        int index = permi + (k%permj);
        wordcomb[c-1] += "" + wordlist[l%size];
        out(l%size + "");
        l++;
    }
    System.out.println(c + ": " + wordcomb[c-1]);
    c++;
}
```

Comment: Enter Words:1 2 3
Entered words: 1 2 3
[1, 2, 3]
------------------> 3 permutations for 1 words combination
 Iterations: 3
0
1: 1
1
2: 2
2
3: 3
------------------> 6 permutations for 2 words combination
 Iterations: 12
0
1
4: 12
2
0
5: 31
1
2
6: 23
0
1
7: 12
2
0
8: 31
1
2
9: 23
------------------> 9 permutations for 3 words combination
 Iterations: 27
0
1
2
10: 123
0
1
2
11: 123
0
1
2
12: 123
0
1
2
13: 123
0
1
2
14: 123
0
1
2
15: 123
0
1
2
16: 123
0
1
2
17: 123
0
1
2
18: 123

Comment: the null problem is solved but the permutations are still not working. Thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is basically caused by printing null String object. Try to check the creation or the printing. There is somewhere String that has null value :)

Answer (score -1):

You should sort by invoking another method

```
Arrays.sort(sortedIDXs, new Comparator<String>() {
 public int compare(String idx1,String idx2) {
    //Your method of sorting here
    //return 1 if string idx1 should be before, 0 if equal and -1 in opposite 
 }
```